# Prestashop Generate Invoice with user name

Tags: pdf, prestashop, invoice

I have been trying to find the file where the pdf invoice is generated to change the name of it, to the name of the user, e.g instead "invoice00012", I would like to have "John Smith.pdf". I would appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: my prestashop version is 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify function `getFilename()` in `classes/pdf/HTMLTemplateInvoice.php`. You get the customer object using `$customer = new Customer((int)$this->order->id_customer);`.

```
public function getFilename()
{   
    $customer = new Customer((int)$this->order->id_customer);

    return $customer->firstname.'_'.$customer->lastname.'.pdf';     
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I couldn't get the username in the getFilename(), I tried this "$this->context->customer"